# Why I get error when I try to change background color?Python Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

So I want to change background color every 5 seconds with this code

```
#:import C kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex
<TrainingTiming>
    FloatLayout:
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: C(root.color)
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
```

I define `root.color` by `StringProperty` in my `.py` file and I get this error

```
Exception ignored in: 'kivy.graphics.instructions.RenderContext.set_state'
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "kivy\graphics\shader.pyx", line 245, in kivy.graphics.shader.Shader.set_uniform
   File "kivy\graphics\shader.pyx", line 284, in kivy.graphics.shader.Shader.upload_uniform
 IndexError: list index out of range
```

My app works but I get this error and I don't know what to do

program example

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock

Colors = ['#f6f946', '#21ac2f', '#d31010']

class TrainingWindow(Screen):
    color = StringProperty()

    def on_enter(self):
        self.colorsnum = 0
        self.schedule = Clock.schedule_interval(self.updatelabel, 5)

    def updatelabel(self, dt):
        global Colors
        if self.colorsnum < len(Colors):
            self.color = Colors[self.colorsnum]
            self.colorsnum += 1

kv = Builder.load_file("main.kv")

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Post a minimal runnable example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @inclement Already did

Comment: `IndexError: list index out of range` is when you have list with i.e. 3 elements but you try to get 4th element. I would check values used in `[ ]` - ie. `self.colorsnum` in `Colors[self.colorsnum]` . But strange is that error doesn't show problem in your code but in Kivy module.

Comment: Is this really a minimal runnable example? Your kv refers to root.color, but root is a FloatLayout and so doesn't have a property of that name.

Comment: I checked it and every seems okay despite this my program works well.

Comment: @inclement yes in whole program it's diffrent i'm gonna edit that

Comment: this is my whole program if it helps https://github.com/BrunoFaliszewski/TrainingTiming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are defining the color as:

```
color = StringProperty()
```

This results in a `color` that is an empty string, that results in an empty list produced by `kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex()`. The `kv`:

```
rgba: C(root.color)
```

then sets the `rgba` to `[]`, causing the `IndexError: list index out of range`.

The fix is to define the `root` property with a default hex color string. For example:

```
color = StringProperty('#d31010')
```

Comment: @BrunoFaliszewski it's nice to mark the answer as accepted in such situation (and upvote if you are particularily happy with it).